# Which article to use if there are multiple winners?

Tags: articles

Consider the following scenario. There are two shops that are closest to my home: *ShopA* and *ShopB*. In other words, both shops are at the same distance and closer than any other shops in the town.

Which of the following statements is/are correct:

1. ShopA is **the** closest shop from my home.
2. ShopA is **a** closest shop from my home.

The first statement seems right to hear. However, there are two closest shops, so the second statement also seems correct. Which statement is correct grammatically?

Comment: A is one of the closest shops from your home.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Thank You. That can also work. However, I would still like to know which of the mentioned statements are correct. Are they both incorrect then?

Comment: 1' 'Shop A is the closest shop to my home' and the more formal 1'' 'Shop A is the shop closest to my home' are grammatical but infelicitous (so wrong for another reason). 2  is unsalvageable.

Comment: The second sentence, exactly as written, is ungrammatical. You can have a single shop that is *closest*, or a group of shops that, collectively, are *closest*. But you can't have multiple shops that, individually, are all *closest*. The rephrased versions of the sentences in the comments are all grammatical (and logical). The original version of the second sentence is not grammatical. However, while the first sentence in the question *is* grammatical, if there are two shops that are the **same** distance from your house, then the first sentence is a logical falsehood.

Comment: @JasonBassford Why can't we have multiple shops, that individually, are all closest?

Comment: Because that's not how English (or logic) works. If something is *closest*, it means *closer than anything else*. It's possible for two things to be equally close, and collectively closer than anything else, but you can't say that A is closest (excluding B) and also that B is closest (excluding A). You can only say that A and B, together, are closest (excluding all other things).